# Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am trying to resync the node with the DAS but every time  i am getting the below CORBA error.

I have checked the /etc/hosts file everything resolving properly.

> [#|2014-11-15T09:04:10.787+0530|FINE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.corba.ORBUtil|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator;MethodName=handleFullLogging;|IOP00410001:
>   Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname:
>   192.168.1.1; port: 3700 org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: FINE: IOP00410001: Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname:
>   192.168.1.1; port: 3700  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor93.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.connectFailure(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:257)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:270)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:129)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:223)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:228)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:194)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl._SerialContextProvider_DynamicStub.lookup(com/sun/enterprise/naming/impl/_SerialContextProvider_DynamicStub.java)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:540)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:540)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>           at com.anish.gbs.util.WCSServiceLookupHelper.getBean(WCSServiceLookupHelper.java:53)
>           at com.fundamo.gbs.filter.WebLayerRenderingFilter.init(WebLayerRenderingFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:264)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:120)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5377)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:219)
>           at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
>           at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
>           at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
>           at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
>           at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
>           at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:253)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(GlassFishDecorator.java:63)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishImpl.start(OSGiGlassFishImpl.java:69)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(GlassFishMain.java:117)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMain.java:97)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused
>           at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:339)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:242)
>           ... 52 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:536)
>           at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.ORBUtility.openSocketChannel(ORBUtility.java:110)
>           at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:324)
>           ... 53 more |#]

Its look like connectivity issue but everything perfect in the connection level , kindly guide me to solve this thread.

Comment: I'm getting this error also: at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:339) Did you ever find out what the problem was?